# Code igniter Logger

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to code igniter and PHP5. From the following url http://techtots.blogspot.in/2011/12/logging-request-parameters-in.html i am trying to create a logger where it logs all the request into a table.My question is where should the following code reside.And how will i specify the table name.

```
class Logger {

private $CI;

public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}

public function request_logger() {
    $uri = $this->CI->uri->uri_string();

        $params = trim(print_r($this->CI->input->post(), TRUE));

    log_message('info', '==============');
    log_message('info', 'URI: ' . $uri);
    log_message('info', '--------------');
    log_message('info', $params);
    log_message('info', '==============');
}
}
```

Comment: you want to store these logs into MYSQL DB table, is that what you mean ?

Comment: YEs i want to log all the request that are hitting the server to log into the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a [library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for this code

And modify it with:

```
private $table_name;
function set_table_name($table_name)
{
   $this->$table_name = $table_name;
}
```

or create constant variable in application/config/constants.php for specify a table name.

Comment: Can u please explain in detail..My first question is where will i include the above shown code..Which file?

Comment: You have to create file /application/libraries/Logger.php and include it in project by autoload method. /application/config/autoload.php -> $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'Logger');

Comment: I have done that now..But where to include your code set_table_name() .My table name is logger.So can u show me what exactly i need to do in my Logger.php

Comment: nowhere. This class currently do nothing. You have to connect it with hooks like in 'Logging request parameters in CodeIgniter'. After that you will see it in /applications/logs

Comment: Do not forget. /application/config.php enable_hooks have be setted as TRUE

Comment: You can set filepath in hooks array as 'libraries' or move logger.php to hooks folder

Comment: After doing everything i get the error as class Logger { private $CI; public function __construct() { $this->CI =& get_instance(); } public function request_logger() { $uri = $this->CI->uri->uri_string(); $params = trim(print_r($this->CI->input->post(), TRUE)); log_message('info', '=============='); log_message('info', 'URI: ' . $uri); log_message('info', '--------------'); log_message('info', $params); log_message('info', '=============='); } }
An Error Was Encountered

Non-existent class: Logger

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21368/discussion-between-rajeev-and-thehorse)